# I get NullPointerException when trying to click button that exists and initialized with PageFactory.initElements()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Say, I have two little tests within one class.

```
public class LoginAndLogout extends BaseTest {

    HomePage kashome = new HomePage();

    @Test(testName = "Login_as")
    public void login() {
        LoginPage loginkas = LoginPage.open(); //open login page
        kashome = loginkas.login(name, pwd);
    }

    @Test
    public void logOut() {
       kashome.logOut();
    }
}
```

HomePage class:

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    public HomePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(Driver.get(), this);
    }
}
```

BasePage class:

```
public class BasePage {
    @FindBy(xpath="//img[@title='Выход']")
    WebElement exitButton;

    @FindBy (xpath="//a[text()='Выход']")
    WebElement exitLink;


    public BasePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(Driver.get(), this);
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(String usr) {
        if (this.usernameText.getText().startsWith(usr)) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public void logOut() {
        try {
            exitLink.click();
            Alert alert = Driver.get().switchTo().alert();
            Reporter.log(alert.getText(), true);
            Reporter.log("Отвечаем ОК", true);
            alert.accept();
        }
        catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Reporter.log(e.getMessage(), true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Reporter.log(e.getMessage(), true);
        }
    }

}
```

1st test runs OK, but on second test I get NPE when trying to execute exitLink.click(), seems like elements in kashome is not initialized, but they are!
There is no @AfterTest methods that could affect tests' behavior.
I checked button's xpath, it's ok.
However, if I add kashome.logOut() to 1st test and delete 2nd one, everything works ok.

Why do I get NPE?

Comment: In what line does the NPE occur?

Comment: @jlordo In exitLink.click() in method logOut

Comment: then (obviously) `exitLink` seems to be `null`.

Comment: @jlordo Sorry, then I don't understand, why is it NOT null when I add kashome.logOut() to 1st test and it is executed there.

Comment: did you add kashome.logOut() after kashome = loginkas.login() where kashome is set?

Comment: @orangegoat if you mean in the same method, then yes, i tried that, it worked ok, but i need two different tests instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

If the `PageFactory` doesn't process the annotations on `exitLink` and `exitButtons`, because those aren't initialized explicitly, they will default to `null` when your `HomePage` instance is created.

I think you are assuming that

```
@FindBy(xpath="//img[@title='Выход']")
WebElement exitButton;

@FindBy (xpath="//a[text()='Выход']")
WebElement exitLink;
```

because of the `@FindBy` annotations, will have values when you run your tests. Annotations on their own don't do anything. You need some processor to read them and, through reflection, set the field they are annotating. If `PageFactory` doesn't do that, those fields will remain null until you set them yourself.

Comment: I thought PageFactory.initElements(Driver.get(), this) will initialize them. As I understood from here [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/PageFactory.html). So I thought when WebElement is referred to, I would get NPE only in case this element doesn't exist. But it exists

Comment: Ok so, reading the javadoc, `PageFactory` takes a `Class` instance, so you are using it wrong. Also, it doesn't do anything to your instance, it creates and returns a new instance.